# How can I install polyglot in Python anaconda?

Tags: python, installation, nlp, anaconda, polyglot

I want to install polyglot library in python anaconda environment but I can't. Can you help me?

```
pip install polyglot
```

My error code:

```
    Complete output (11 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying icu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying PyICU.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying docs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_icu' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\sy\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-whiht1cx\\pyicu_635b71acf5c54c90ac9cff1c627151b2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-whiht1cx\\pyicu_635b71acf5c54c90ac9cff1c627151b2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0n7v7c8v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\sy\anaconda3\Include\PyICU' Check the logs for full command output.
```